# How can you sequentially show the characters within a string in a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

In a UILabel, can you have a string be displayed so that it fills in, character-by-character? For example, if the label text is "IPHONE", I'd like to display "I", then "IP", then "IPH", all the way to "IPHONE."

How could I have a label display text in this fashion?

Comment: What do you mean by "showing them one by one"?

Comment: If the label text is IPHONE means First I,then IP, then IPH, then IPHO, then IPHON, then IPHONE @H2CO3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you want to display the first letter of a string, then after some time its second letter, etc. Solution: use a timer which invokes a method periodically; that method would set the text appropriately:

```
NSString *theTextToDisplay = @"Hello world!";

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.33
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(timerShoot:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

- (void)timerShoot:(NSTimer *)tmr
{
    static int pos = 1;
    theUILabel.text = [theTextToDisplay substringToIndex:pos];
    if (++pos > theTextToDisplay.length) {
        [tmr invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a follow up question. Would there be a way to word wrap the text if it spans 2 lines?

Comment: @tbag yes, check the docs of the `numberOfLines` property of UILabel.

Comment: Just checked the docs. So just setting numberOfLines to 0 should do the trick? Thanks! I'll give this a try.

Comment: @tbag Yes, and you may also want to set the height of the label to something reasonably high.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example and just a logic for display the text one by one with animation..

first add the `UILable` with bellow frame and then set text like bellow...

```
 yourLable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 112, 0, yourLable.frame.size.height); 
 yourLable.text = @"IPHONE";
```

after that call this bellow method when you want to show the `UILable`

```
-(IBAction)btnLableShow_Clicked:(id)sender
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];

    yourLable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 112, 220, yourLable.frame.size.height);  // set width with your requirement
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: its working .thank yu. while animation the label move up ,is it possible to stop tat movement

Comment: may be you can set the frame outside of this method or after call this method with thread otherwise you can set directly the frame which you want but static, not dynamic for dynamic you can set the logic..